# Efficient way to group all equal objects defined by IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, iequalitycomparer, equivalence

I have a big list of certain objects that are of type `Order`. Furthermore, I have defined an `IEqualityComparer<Order>` and my goal is to efficiently create a list of lists (or groupings) where every sublist contains the objects that are equal to each other. Mathematically, I have an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) (IEqualityComparer) and want to have a list of all [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation#Equivalence_class). I thought about using `HashSet<Order>`, `Dictionary<>` or `Lookup<>` but they dont seem to be perfect for my case. So any ideas?

Comment: The `ToLookup` should be perfect for this.

Comment: `var grouped = sequence.ToLookup(x => x.Whatever, comparer);` - it simply could be `.ToLookup(x => x, comparer)` in your case

Comment: Maybe I am confused that Lookup needs a key and I dont care about it. So you propose to choose whatever as a key and dont mind further about it?

Comment: @T_D you already *chose* what to use as a key when you made an `IEqualityComparer<Order>` - that **defines**: "I'm using `Order` as the key". Since it is the key you will be comparing, if you want to use a different key, you'll need a suitable comparer. That could be an `IEqualityComparer<string>` for example (there are lots inbuilt), using `x => x.Foo`

Answer (score 0):

I think this something like this shluod to the job:

```
var uniqueItems = yourRawList.Distinct(yourComparer);
var result = uniqueItems.Select(i => new List<Order>(yourRawList.Where(o =>yourComparer.Equals(i, o))));
```